# Can't Expand Firebase Notifications

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I've made an app using Firebase Auth and Messaging, I keep sending notifications to app through Firebase Console, the problem is I can't expand the notification if it is big. How do I do it? Help Me

```
public class FirebaseNots extends FirebaseMessagingService {


private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
    // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
    // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
    // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
    // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
    // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
    // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
    // [END_EXCLUDE]

    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    // Not getting messages here? See why this may be: 
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
}
// [END receive_message]

/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
 *
 * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
 */
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
  }
```

[Image Please Take A Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mafyj.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need add a [BigTextStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle.html) to your notification if you want it to be expandable to show multiple lines:

```
notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(messageBody));
```

Comment: Your code doesn't actually call your `sendNotification()` method - where do you actually call it?

Comment: Where do i need to call it?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is fixed in the next release of FCM which will be release very soon.

Keep an eye on https://firebase.google.com/support/releases for the next android release and update the version of the library in you app :)

Comment: Seems like never get fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Notifications from the Firebase console do not yet support BigStyle notifications. This is a known issue and they are working on a fix, as a workaround send your notifications using the REST API using data messages, then when the message is received generate the notification yourself like @ianhanniballake is suggesting.

Comment: thanks man! I'm new to this things, do you have any tutorial or anything which i can proceed further?

Comment: See FCM docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream and Android notification docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html.

Comment: Seems like never get fixed?